# Redux connect chaining async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am in the process of trying to setup redux, react-redux and redux-thunk. Thinks are generally going well but I have a question about how things are supposed to look when chaining multiple async actions together.

Specifically I have a scenario where the actions can be invoked individually or indirectly by another action which can invoke them. My question is how should `selectItem` be authored if I want to be idiomatic?

**action.js**

```
export function fetchByContext(contextId) { 
    return dispatch => {
        _fetchByContext(messages => { 
            dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_MESSAGES, ... });
        });
    };
};

export function subscribeByContext(contextId) {
    return dispatch => {
        _subscribeByContext(messages => { 
            dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_MESSAGES, ... });
        });
    };
};

export function selectItem(contextId) {
    return dispatch => {
        subscribeByContext(contextId)(dispatch);
        fetchByContext(contextId)(dispatch);
    };
};
```

Comment: async,await keywork maybe can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key is that ([ref](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition)):

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the return value of dispatch itself

If the inner functions of `fetchByContext()`, `subscribeByContext()` return a promise, these could be chained in series or run in parallel from `selectItem()`. An untested implementation, assuming neither `_fetchByContext()` nor `_subscribeByContext()` return a promise would be:

```
export function fetchByContext(contextId) { 
    return dispatch => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            _fetchByContext(messages => { 
                dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_MESSAGES, ... });
                resolve(messages);
            });
        });
    };
};

export function subscribeByContext(contextId) {
    return dispatch => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            _subscribeByContext(messages => { 
                dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_MESSAGES, ... });
                resolve(messages);
            });
        });
    };
};

export function selectItem(contextId) {
    return dispatch => {
        // CALL IN SERIES
        return dispatch(subscribeByContext(contextId))
            .then(() => dispatch(fetchByContext(contextId)));
        // CALL IN PARALLEL (alternative to the code above; this is probably not what you want - just keeping for reference)
        return Promise.all(
            dispatch(subscribeByContext(contextId)),
            dispatch(fetchByContext(contextId))
        );
    };
}
```

Again please note the code above is untested, just in hope of giving an idea for the general solution.